# Как получать заглавие кнопки при нажатии на него swift 3

Tags: swift, button, swift3, xib

Создал `Keyboard.xib` и `Keyboard.swift` и запускаю его в `TableViewController`
Мне надо при нажатии на кнопку в `Keyboard.xib`выдавал `currentTitle`

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
  func keyWasTapped(character: String)
}

class Keyboard: UIView {

weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn10: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn11: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn12: UIButton!


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initializeSubviews()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initializeSubviews()
}

func initializeSubviews() {
    let xibFileName = "Keyboard"
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
    btn1.clipsToBounds = true
    btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn2.clipsToBounds = true
    btn2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn3.clipsToBounds = true
    btn3.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn4.clipsToBounds = true
    btn4.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn5.clipsToBounds = true
    btn5.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn6.clipsToBounds = true
    btn6.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn7.clipsToBounds = true
    btn7.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn8.clipsToBounds = true
    btn8.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn9.clipsToBounds = true
    btn9.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn10.clipsToBounds = true
    btn10.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn11.clipsToBounds = true
    btn11.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    btn12.clipsToBounds = true
    btn12.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
}

@IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: sender.currentTitle!)
    let number = sender.currentTitle!
    print(number)
  }
}
```

Каждую кнопку связал с 
`@IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton)`
Не помогает, не печатает мне `currentTilte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через `sender.title(for: .normal)` способ:

```
@IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
  if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
    print(buttonTitle)
  }
}
```

Если не получается, то попробуйте через `sender.titleLabel.text`, где-то видел подобное:

```
@IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
  if let buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel.text {
    print(buttonTitle)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: sender.title(for: .normal))
    let number = sender.title(for: .normal)
    print(number)
}
```

Comment: Пробывал но, не помогло.